# Tmux won't start under WSL2

Tags: permissions, tmux

Tmux fails to start with

```
error creating /run/user/$(id -u)/tmux-1000 (No such file or directory)
```

But starts fine under root

Comment: What is the distro that you are running in WSL2? is it the default Ubuntu, or something else? is `TMUX_TMPDIR` set in your user environment?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. TMUX_TMPDIR is not set, and I have to similar problem with GNU Screen. It seems that /run is not writable under unprivileged user

Comment: As a workaround, you could try setting `TMUX_TMPDIR=/tmp`, which AFAIK is the "traditional" value (and appears to be what tmux uses on Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL1)

Comment: Is `TMPDIR` set (not `TMUX_TMPDIR`)?  That would explain why it is happening for both `tmux` and `screen`.  I'm running WSL2 (and WSL1) Ubuntu 20.04 and both are correctly using `/tmp/tmux-1000`.  Figuring out why temp files are trying to go to `/run` is pretty much the core issue, it sounds like.

Comment: For me exporting `export TMUX_TMPDIR='/tmp'` in my .zshrc worked on openSuse Tumbleweed with tmux 3.2